# Preload images using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

When I scroll through my RecyclerView the first time, my images load slowly. After that they are there instantly without any waiting time until I close my app. I want to preload like 5-10 images so scrolling is smoother, so here is what I have tried:

```
Glide
    .with(getContext())
    .load(getResources().getIdentifier("item"+(listIndex+7, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName()))
    .diskCacheStrategy(ALL)
    .preload(120,60);
}
```

That was supposed to preload the 7th image that comes next into cache. Then my normal image loads:

```
Glide
    .with(getContext())
    .load(getResources().getIdentifier("item"+(listIndex), "drawable", getContext().getPackageName()))
    .diskCacheStrategy(ALL)
    .into((ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageH));
}
```

But even now the images still take time to load while scrolling.

Comment: Try using .dontAnimate()  before you write .into(ImageView)

Comment: Hi. Did you find way?